# Select records with IDs containing in another table

Tags: postgresql

```
vit=# select count(*) from evtags;
  count  
---------
 4496914

vit=# explain select tag from evtags where evid in (1002, 1023);
                              QUERY PLAN                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using evtags_pkey on evtags  (cost=0.00..15.64 rows=12 width=7)
   Index Cond: (evid = ANY ('{1002,1023}'::integer[]))
```

This seems completely ok so far. Next, I want to use IDs from another table instead of specifying them in the query.

```
vit=# select count(*) from zzz;
 count 
-------
 49738
```

Here we go...

```
vit=# explain select tag from evtags where evid in (select evid from zzz);
                              QUERY PLAN                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Semi Join  (cost=1535.11..142452.47 rows=291712 width=7)
   Hash Cond: (evtags.evid = zzz.evid)
   ->  Seq Scan on evtags  (cost=0.00..69283.14 rows=4496914 width=11)
   ->  Hash  (cost=718.38..718.38 rows=49738 width=4)
         ->  Seq Scan on zzz  (cost=0.00..718.38 rows=49738 width=4)
```

Why index scan on the much more larger table and what's the correct way to do this?

**EDIT**

I recreated my `zzz` table and now it is better for some reason:

```
vit=# explain analyze select tag from evtags where evid in (select evid from zzz);
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=708.00..2699.17 rows=2248457 width=7) (actual time=28.935..805.923 rows=244353 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=708.00..710.00 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=28.893..54.461 rows=38822 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on zzz  (cost=0.00..601.80 rows=42480 width=4) (actual time=0.032..10.985 rows=40000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using evtags_pkey on evtags  (cost=0.00..9.89 rows=6 width=11) (actual time=0.015..0.017 rows=6 loops=38822)
         Index Cond: (evid = zzz.evid)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 825.651 ms
```

But after several executions it changes to

```
vit=# explain analyze select tag from evtags where evid in (select evid from zzz);
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Semi Join  (cost=4184.11..127258.48 rows=235512 width=7) (actual time=38.269..1461.755 rows=244353 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (evtags.evid = zzz.evid)
   ->  Index Only Scan using evtags_pkey on evtags  (cost=0.00..136736.89 rows=4496914 width=11) (actual time=0.038..899.647 rows=3630070 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
   ->  Materialize  (cost=4184.04..4384.04 rows=40000 width=4) (actual time=38.212..61.038 rows=40000 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=4184.04..4284.04 rows=40000 width=4) (actual time=38.208..51.104 rows=40000 loops=1)
               Sort Key: zzz.evid
               Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 552kB
               ->  Seq Scan on zzz  (cost=0.00..577.00 rows=40000 width=4) (actual time=0.018..8.833 rows=40000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 1484.293 ms
```

...Which is actually slower. Is there any way to hint it a 'correct' execution plan?

The point of these operations is that I want to perform number of queries on a subset of my data and wanted to use separate temporary table to hold IDs of records I want to process.

Comment: Do your tables have primary/foreign keys (there is no index scan, there could be two) Do you have valid statistics ? Please add the table definitions, including PK/FK and/or indexes. BTW: this kind of plan is normal if the result set is small and most of the tuples are needed. BTW2: `explain analyze` will show you *both* the estimated and measured counts/numbers.

Comment: Did you run `vacuum analyze` after recreating the `zzz` table? (it will update the statistics) Also: the "outer" table needs about 50% of the rows, an index might not help in finding them (since basically every disk page will be needed anyway). You *could* try lowering random_page_cost to 1.5 (or work_mem to a smaller value) to force an index scan, but that will only make sense when fewer rows/pages need to be fetched. BTW: Does the zzz table have PK/FK/indices? **please add the table definitions** , including PK/FK/indexes.

Answer (score 1):

An inner join has a better chance of a good plan:

```
select e.tag
from
    evtags e
    inner join
    zzz z using (evid)
```

Or this:

```
select e.tag
from evtags e
where exists (
    select 1
    from zzz
    where evid = e.evid
)
```

As pointed in the comments run `analyze evtags; analyze zzz;`